# why Hash value gets affected in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

```
mainhash = { 'A' => [ 0,1,2,3,4  ]  , 'B' => [ 0 ,1,2 ,3 ]  } 

ahash = mainhash['A']

indval = ahash.shift
```

`ahash` become as follows

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

and `mainhash` become as follows

```
{"A"=>[1, 2, 3, 4], "B"=>[0, 1, 2, 3]}
```

I  am manipulating `ahash`  variable by shifting some values from ahash, When I do this operation it affects the mainhash value. Why it is happening?

Am  I missing any conceptual understanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `ahash` and `mainhash` both have references to the same `Array` instance. If you modify this through `ahash`, referenced object is being modified, so no wonder it changes also in `mainhash`.

To operate on copy (shallow copy, to be precise) of the object instead of the same object, you should use `dup` method:

```
ahash = mainhash['A'].dup
```

Answer (score 3):

Look [`Array#shift`](http://yard.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#shift-instance_method)

> *Removes the first element of self and returns it (shifting all other elements down by one*). Returns nil if the array is empty.

```
mainhash = { 'A' => [ 0,1,2,3,4  ]  , 'B' => [ 0 ,1,2 ,3 ]  } 

ahash = mainhash['A']
p ahash.object_id # => 8577888
p mainhash['A'].object_id # => 8577888
p indval = ahash.shift # => 0
```

As above seen, `ahash` and `mainhash['A']` refer to the same Array object `[ 0,1,2,3,4]`, thus changing `ahash#shift` causes `0` to be removed from `ahash` which also causes `0` to be removed from `mainhash['A']`.

Said that your *Hash* becomes as below :

```
mainhash
# => {"A"=>[1, 2, 3, 4], "B"=>[0, 1, 2, 3]}
```

All operations are legitimate and happened as documented to the link,I have given above.

> *How can I avoid affecting the mainhash*

**As @Marek Lipka said :**

*you should use dup method: ahash = mainhash['A'].dup*.

```
mainhash = { 'A' => [ 0,1,2,3,4  ]  , 'B' => [ 0 ,1,2 ,3 ]  } 

ahash = mainhash['A'].dup
ahash.object_id # => 8577516
mainhash['A'].object_id # => 8577600
indval = ahash.shift # => 0
ahash # => [1, 2, 3, 4]
mainhash['A'] # => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: How can I avoid affecting the mainhash , but still I want to take a copy and do manipulation

Comment: @Pavunkumar you should use `dup` method: `ahash = mainhash['A'].dup`.

Answer (score 0):

> Why it is happening ?.

```
arr = [1, 2, 3]
x = arr

arr.shift

p arr
p x

--output:--
[2, 3]
[2, 3]
```

arr and x both refer to the same array.  Assignment ('=') does not create a copy.

Now look at this code:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3]
x = arr.dup

arr.shift
p arr
p x

--output:--
[2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

And by the way, the name 'ahash' is a terrible name for an array.